# MySQL getConnection() is crashing for no reason

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, wamp

I have a strange problem at my work PC and maybe you could be the problem solver. I'm currently developing in jee and I have issues regarding MySQL DB.

Let's say I have this :

```
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{

//Simple select query on my MySQL DB

System.out.println("foo");

}
```

And my output is:

> foo, foo, foo, foo

As you can see, somehow my for loop stops at 4 iterations.
But after some long debugging I found out that somehow the getConnection() is stuck in a thread and even after 2 hours of waiting it's still blocked. The problem is however more complicated because it is not crashing every time on the same getConnection().

My older projects don't work either so I guess it isn't a code problem. I tried to reinstall Eclipse, WampServer, change to Java 1.7 (I'm currently 1.8), tried tomcat 9 (I'm currently tomcat 8), I've deleted and reimported a wholly fresh and new DB in case of there was some corrupted data. Tried a new workspace with a new project, I've also updated my libs and jars that I use in build path and runtime.

But it stills doesn't work and it's becoming really really frustrating. So if you have an idea let me know.

Comment: What is in the MySQL logs? What is the form of the query? Is it likely to be slow? What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show on the server at the time of the waiting query?

Comment: You need to show more code - how (and when) you create the connection, and how you release it. Could be that you are draining the connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a stroke of genius I found the issue.

The problem was the size of the memcached --> changed it to 245760 from 512

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering.

Last line of my MySQL Logs : Query  SELECT count(*) FROM a_lcolang WHERE wsId=17474. 
So as we can see, this is a real simple query.

[My show full processlist log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7iaN.png)

The thing about how I create connection and how I realease it isn't the issue in my opinion because I use method who exists have been around for a really long time. Not to mention it doesn't work anymore on older projects which were working totally fine (if not the prod would already be down).